# matching columns in two files with different line numbers

Tags: awk

This is a rather repeated question but I could not figure it out with my files, so, any help will be highly appreciated.

I have two files, I want to compare their first fields and print the common lines into a third file, an example of my files:

file 1:

```
gene1
gene2
gene3
```

file 2:

```
gene1|trans1|12|233|345 45
gene1|trans2|12|342|232 45
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 12
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 45
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 12 
gene2|trans3|12|34r|343 325 
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 545
gene3|trans4|12|344|333 454
gene3|trans2|12|343|343 545 
gene3|trans3|12|344|343 45
gene4|trans2|12|344|343 2112
gene4|trans2|12|344|343 455
```

file 2 contains more fields. Please pay attention that the first field is not exactly like the first file but the gene element only matches.

The output should look like this:

```
gene1|trans1|12|233|345 45
gene1|trans2|12|342|232 45
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 12
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 45
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 12 
gene2|trans3|12|34r|343 325 
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 545
gene3|trans4|12|344|333 454
gene3|trans2|12|343|343 545 
gene3|trans3|12|344|343 45
```

I use this code, it does not give me any error but it does not give me any output either:

```
awk '{if (f[$1] != FILENAME) a[$1]++; f[$1] = FILENAME; } END{ for (i in a) if (a[i] > 1) print i; }' file1 file1
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Some like this?

```
awk -F\| 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++;next} $1 in a' file1 file2
gene1|trans1|12|233|345 45
gene1|trans2|12|342|232 45
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 12
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 45
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 12
gene2|trans3|12|34r|343 325
gene2|trans2|12|344|343 545
gene3|trans4|12|344|333 454
gene3|trans2|12|343|343 545
gene3|trans3|12|344|343 45
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, `grep` is sufficient:

```
grep -w -f file1 file2
```